# python sqlite 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the `sqlite3` in python.

I've created a table in the database. The table has some `NULL` values

```
import sqlite3
engine = sqlite3.connect('Practice')
BST = pd.DataFrame({'N':[1,3,5,7,2,6,4,8,10,12,14,9,13,11,15],'P':[2,2,6,6,4,4,15,9,9,13,13,11,11,15,'NULL']})
BST.to_sql(name = "BST", con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

Then I want to create a view of this table

```
pd.read_sql_query("CREATE VIEW V1 as select P from BST",con=engine)
```

But it throws an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

I wonder how should I create a view of a table in sqlite when the table contains `NULL` value?

Comment: i think you can't read sql and create a view in the same time

Comment: @PRMoureu thanks! So `df.to_sql()` is a pandas function so as to either create a real table in the database or create a view (which occupies less memory than create an actual table?) in the database that can be refer to later, am I right? `pd.read_sql_query()` is really just read the sql query and fetch the rows, columns in the created table (or view) in the database?

Comment: no i made a mistake, you must use `engine.execute` to create that view

Comment: @PRMoureu But actually I used your 1st version and it works pretty well. I even wrote a 2nd query that use the view `V1`....

Comment: The real question is why is it working, because we were not creating a view, but a table named 'CREATE VIEW V1 as select P from BST', i will take a look later

Comment: @PRMoureu I see! you are right, we just created a table. Then, since we can create many tables, why we need to create view? is that because sometimes we don't want to store some tables created in the intermediate step, so we create view? but I remember after finished a query, we'd better also delete the view right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be like this :

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
engine = sqlite3.connect('Practice')
BST = pd.DataFrame({'N':[1,3,5,7,2,6,4,8,10,12,14,9,13,11,15],'P':[2,2,6,6,4,4,15,9,9,13,13,11,11,15,'NULL']})
BST.to_sql(name = "BST", con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False) 

engine.execute("CREATE VIEW V1 as select P from BST")

print(pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * from V1', con=engine))
```